# Enzyme Can’t Find React Sub-Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component called `<DateRange />` which basically renders two `<DateTime />` components. Below is the relevant code in the `DateRange` class:

```
return (
        <div className="dateRange">
            <DateTime name={sname} className='date-time-picker'/>
            <DateTime name={ename} className='date-time-picker'/>
        </div>
    )
```

I have another react component called `<Form />` which receives an Object in its `props` telling it what components to render and how. The part of its code which renders the `<DateRange />` components is this:

```
else if (ip.type.name == 'DateRange')
    return (
        <div key={i} className="inlineCont">
            <label {...ip.labelProps}><span>{ip.label}</span></label>
            <ip.type onChange={this.handleInputChange} validate={this.updateState} 
                disabled={this.state.submitting} values={this.state.inputs} 
                def={ip.def}/>
        </div>);
```

I am using Jest and Ezyme to write unit tests. But I am unable to access the `<DateTime />` components in Enzyme.

Here’s what I did:

```
const inputs = [{ *blabla* }];
var wrapper = mount(<Form inputs={inputs} className="frame1-body" />);
console.log("----> DateTime found: "+wrapper.find("DateTime").length);
```

The last line gives 0. I displayed the exact code in a different page and the date inputs are rendered correctly. I just can’t let Enzyme *point*  to them I guess.

How can I access the `<DateTime />` components which are rendered by the `<DateRange />` component which are rendered by my main `<Form />` wrapper?

Comment: Can you try finding DateTime by the constructor instead? I.e. `wrapper.find(DateTime)`. Just import DateTime into the test. Also, put a cnsole.log in your dateRange render method and see if it gets called when you run the unit test.

Comment: OK I’ll try that and let you know how it goes.